# Reading data while HTTP response code is 401

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from a connection which returns `401` using indigenous Java but couldn't succeed. Below is the code-

```
public String doGet(URL url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        int readByte;
        while ( (readByte = stream.read()) != -1 )
        {
            data.append((char) readByte);

        }
        stream.close();
        return data.toString();
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

While using `SOAP UI` tool, I can read the same URL easily. See the below screenshot-

[image]

What is missing? Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 1):

When you get an error response, the content is not received via the standard input stream.  Instead you need to use [`HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29) to get an `InputSteam` to read the content of the error page.

Comment: Reading error stream is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException` with `stream .read()` method. :( What to do now ?

Comment: @RaviJoshi Check the link to the documentation.  This means that you're getting `null` from `getErrorStream` method call - which in turn means that there was no connection established.  Are you sure you get 401? What is the actual exception thrown?

Comment: I put a `sysout` in between `HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();` and `InputStream stream = connection.getErrorStream();` got `401`

Comment: @RaviJoshi Try explicitly calling `connection.connect()` after `openConnection()` but before calling `getInputStream()`.  This will likely throw `IOException`.  In `catch` for that exception, try getting the error stream.

Comment: No, Its not throwing any exception. `stream .read()` is throwing null pointer.